# Compare 2 columns with different frequencies in a data frame using a window in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I would like to compare 2 columns of a dataframe that have different frequencies. The column with the smaller frequency fill with the same value during the period of the biggest frequency, for example if we have frequency of column 1 4 times lower than column 2:

```
column1 column2
1       4
1       3
1       8
1       6
2       7
2       8
2       5
2       10
3       12
3       7
3       0
3       3
```

We can see how the value of column 1 is repeated. What I would like to do is compare using a centered window with the size of 4 (because frec2/frec1 = 4) and get the maximum in this comparison. So we have to obtain 3 values, because there are only 3 different values in the column of lowest frequency. The results must be:

```
1 compared with 4,3,8,6
2 compared with 7,8,5,10
3 compared with 12,7,0,3
```

and them get the maximum difference in absolute value, in this case the three result values will be:

```
7 (abs(1 - 8))
8 (abs(2 - 10))
9 (abs(3 - 12))
```

How could I do this operation having a generic data frame composed by this two columns?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the absolute values of `column1` minus `column2`.  Then group by unique values of `column1` and get the max of those absolute values for each unique value of `column1`, as follows:

```
df['column1'].sub(df['column2']).abs().groupby(df['column1']).max()
```

**Result:**

```
column1
1    7
2    8
3    9
dtype: int64
```

If you want the result presented as a dataframe, you can use:

```
df['column1'].sub(df['column2']).abs().groupby(df['column1']).max().reset_index(name='max_diff')
```

(we name the new column as `max_diff`):

Result:

```
   column1  max_diff
0        1         7
1        2         8
2        3         9
```